# How much percentage of non-free softwares do Ubuntu's repositories contain?

Tags: repository, proprietary

Debian's [documentation](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_debian_is_100_free_software) does mention that:

> Please note that the number of non-free and contrib packages is **less than 2%** of that of main packages.

Debian have three [components](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#component) of repository: **main** (which include 100% [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html)s), **contrib** (which includes free softwares that depends upon non-free softwares) and **non-free** (which contains [proprietary](https://www.gnu.org/proprietary/proprietary.html) softwares). So, the documentation is saying that less than 2% of that of main packages are contained in non-free and contrib repositories.

I want to know the same thing for Ubuntu. Ubuntu has free softwares on **main** and **universe** repositories and **restricted** and **multiverse** [components](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#Components) of repositories contain non-free softwares.

Now, how much percentage of non-free softwares are contained by these restricted and multiverse repositories compared to that of main and universe repositories? Do we have any such analysis?

Comment: have you installed "vrms" yet? :)

Comment: @Rinzwind I am on Debian actually.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/vrms :=) Only works for installed packages though :D So in theory you can install all packages and then do "count all", "count non-free" and there is your percentage. But I probably would start to doubt the "2%"  claim too. Where is the proof? :)

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, `vrms` is already installed on my system.

Comment: see! that claim is not correct >:-D  Now do Ubuntu :D

Comment: @Pandya, does this help? https://trisquel.info/gl/forum/ubuntu-1804-64bit-how-much-non-free-software

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though I didn't find such information on Ubuntu's documentation, I created a simple script to calculate it manually:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

ubuntu_main=$(lynx -dump http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | grep ^Package: | wc -l)
ubuntu_universe=$(lynx -dump http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | grep ^Package: | wc -l)
ubuntu_restricted=$(lynx -dump http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | grep ^Package: | wc -l)
ubuntu_multiverse=$(lynx -dump http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | grep ^Package: | wc -l)

percentage="($ubuntu_restricted+$ubuntu_multiverse)/($ubuntu_main+$ubuntu_universe)"

echo "Total number of packages on Ubuntu's main repository = $ubuntu_main"
echo "Total number of packages on Ubuntu's universe repository = $ubuntu_universe"
echo "Total number of packages on Ubuntu's restricted repository = $ubuntu_restricted"
echo "Total number of packages on Ubuntu's multivrese repository = $ubuntu_multiverse"

echo "Percentage of non-free packages on Ubuntu's repositories= $(echo $percentage*100 | bc -l) %"
```

Output:

```
$ ./sample 
Total Packages on Ubuntu's main repository = 6090
Total number of packages on Ubuntu's universe repository = 53206
Total number of packages on Ubuntu's restricted repository = 143
Total number of packages on Ubuntu's multivrese repository = 813
Percentage of non-free packages = 1.61225040474905558500 %
```

---

For Debian GNU/Linux:

```bsh
$ cat sample 
#!/bin/bash

debian_main=$(lynx -dump http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | grep ^Package: | wc -l)
debian_contrib=$(lynx -dump http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | grep ^Package: | wc -l)
debian_nonfree=$(lynx -dump http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | grep ^Package: | wc -l)

percentage="($debian_contrib+$debian_nonfree)/($debian_main)"

echo "Total number of packages on Debian's main repository = $debian_main"
echo "Total number of packages on Debian's contrib repository = $debian_contrib"
echo "Total number of packages on Debian's non-free repository = $debian_nonfree"

echo "Percentage of non-free packages on Debian GNU/Linux = $(echo $percentage*100 | bc -l) %"
```

```
$ ./sample 
Total number of packages on Debian's main repository = 56873
Total number of packages on Debian's contrib repository = 293
Total number of packages on Debian's non-free repository = 602
Percentage of non-free packages on Debian GNU/Linux = 1.57368171188437395600 %
```

Note: update and backport repositories are not considered for this analysis

Comment: Cool :D +1 :D :D

Comment: But what does non-free actually mean for Ubuntu?  Are they just more lax than Debian and call things "free" that Debian does not?